# Exercise around $\Delta(P)(X)=P(X+1)-P(X)$

Tags: polynomials

I got an exercise in which we define the application $\displaystyle \Delta : \mathbb{R}_{2p+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{2p+1}$ defined as
$$
\Delta(P)(X)=P(X+1)-P(X)
$$
I also have a sequence of polynomials element given by
$$
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}, \ 
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle B_0(x)=1\\  
\displaystyle B'_n(x)=B_{n-1}(x)\\
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}B_n(t)\text{d}t=0
\end{cases}
$$
A first question was to find Ker$(\Delta)$ and to show that $\text{Im}\left(\Delta\right)=\mathbb{R}_p\left[X\right]$.

What I have done is to consider the equation $\displaystyle \forall X , \ P\left(X+1\right)=P\left(X\right)$ so $P(0)=P(n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Hence the polynomial $X \mapsto P(X)-P(0)$ has an infinite number of roots so $P(X)=P(0)$. With the reciprocal
$$
\text{Ker}\left(\Delta\right)=\mathbb{R}_0\left[X\right]
$$
And using that $\text{Im}\left(\Delta\right) \subset \mathbb{R}_p\left[X\right]$ and the equality of dimension i've the result. Is this okay ?
However I need to prove now that there exists a unique polynomial $Q$ such that
$$
\Delta\left(Q\right)\left(X\right)=\frac{X^p}{p!} \text{ and }\int_{0}^{1}Q\left(t\right)\text{d}t=0
$$
I know this polynomial $Q$ exists because of $\displaystyle X \mapsto X^p/p! \in \mathbb{R}_p\left[X\right]$. But supposing $Q$ and $S$ to be two polynomials satisfying those conditions, I 'm stuck proving they are equal. How can I do that ? I just obtained
$$
\int_{0}^{1}S\left(X+1\right)\text{d}X=\int_{0}^{1}Q\left(X+1\right)\text{d}X=\frac{1}{\left(p+1\right)!}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You should have observed that for any $p$,  $\Delta$ maps $\mathbb R_p[X]$ to $\mathbb R_{p-1}[X]$. As you showed, $\ker \Delta = \mathbb R_0[X]$, the set of constant polynomials. By the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim \operatorname{im} \Delta = p$, thus $\Delta$ is surjective (when considered as a linear map between $\mathbb R_p[X]$ and $\mathbb R_{p-1}[X]$).

Therefore, there exists $Q\in \mathbb R_{p+1}[X]$ such that $\Delta Q = X^p/p!$. Choose $\alpha\in \mathbb R$ such that $\int_0^1 (Q+\alpha) =0$ and note that we still have $\Delta(Q+\alpha) = X^p/p!$.

If $R$ is also such that $\Delta R = X^p/p!$ and $\int_0^1 R = 0$, then by linearity $\Delta (Q+\alpha-R)=0$, thus $Q+\alpha-R$ is constant. But $\int_0^1 (Q+\alpha-R)=0$, hence $Q+\alpha-R = 0$. So $Q+\alpha$ is unique.

Comment: Couldnt I only say that $\Delta\left(Q-R\right)=0$ hence $Q-R \in \text{Ker}\left(\Delta\right)$ and with $\int_{0}^{1}Q-R=0$ i've $Q=R$ ?

Comment: @Atmos yes, but you need to justify why you can choose $Q$ such that $\int_0^1 Q = 1$.